# Missing files in Loader_Generate_Nation_Script for TIGER geocoder

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I'm while running

```
CREATE SCHEMA
Archive:  tl_2015_us_state.zip
 extracting: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.cpg  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.dbf  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.prj  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.shp  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.shp.ea.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.shp.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.shp.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2015_us_state.shx  
unzip:  cannot find or open */tl_*state.zip, */tl_*state.zip.zip or */tl_*state.zip.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
```

This keeps happening for latter steps:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open */tl_*county.zip, */tl_*county.zip.zip or */tl_*county.zip.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
```

Do I need to get those from a different source?

EDIT:

It seems to be a problem with the paths:

It downloads the files:

```
  ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/ADDR/PLACE/tl_*_17_*
           => ‘ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/ADDR/PLACE/.listing’
Resolving ftp2.census.gov (ftp2.census.gov)... 148.129.75.35, 2610:20:2010:a09:1000:0:9481:4b23
```

Can't go to the corresponding path:

```
 cd: can't cd to /tmp/gis/gisdata//ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/ADDR/PLACE
```

The dir only exist until:

```
/tmp/gis/gisdata//ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/ADDR/
```

It Doesn't find the downloaded files:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open tl_*_17*_place.zip, tl_*_17*_place.zip.zip or tl_*_17*_place.zip.ZIP.
```

Also, this other directory is missing:

```
No such directory ‘geo/tiger/TIGER2015/ADDR/PLACE’.
```

At which point should they be created?

Comment: Did you data load?  I think there was an issue with extra *.zip attempts which you can ignore.  It's hard to tell if that is what you are running to or running into Census banning your IP.  I've had issues with Census akamai firewall blocking downloads.  Usually happens after a state or 2 of downloads though, not right away.

Comment: @LR1234567 It worked for the first two states I downloaded, Now I'm getting issues with the others, is not working. Is there any way to fix the firewall blocking? I think I could be that

Comment: Sadly not that I know of I tried calling census about this but could never get in touch with the right people.